# Interactive software to organize and present information

Tags: osx, data-visualization, information-management, user-interface, multi-user

**Example:** I have a bunch of different fruits and for each one I have 10 categories (e.g., color, size, taste, etc.)

#### What I am looking for

- A program for only the person in charge to edit the information and the user to view it and click around  (like viewing it on a website).
- The interactive part of it would be for the user to click on the particular fruit name and have the information come up upon selecting that fruit (I don't want everything to be presented simultaneously).
- I would like the software to be light and have a fresh design and preferably be able to edit the viewing options (colors, fonts, etc.) myself.
- For Mac, price range is flexible

#### Note

- I am not looking for a spreadsheet or bookkeeping type of software
- This would be like an application for the user. Log in, go to the menu of different fruits, click on the fruit, have the info come up.

Comment: Do both users (the one editing, and the one viewing) use the same computer account? Or does the viewing-user gets their own client, and the new fruit data needs to be imported somehow?

Comment: The fruit data would need to be imported by the editing user and visualized to the viewer. Ideally, each viewer would have an account or some sort of a password access permission to the data.

Answer (score 1):

This answer focuses on the data, not on any particular app.

You could use the Wikidata Query Service to get started:

Pictures of fruit - see Picture captions for Links to Fruit Properties:
https://w.wiki/3SCk or https://w.wiki/3SCt

```
#Fruit, with pictures
#defaultView:ImageGrid
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?pic
WHERE
{
?item wdt:P31 wd:Q3314483 .
?item wdt:P18 ?pic
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
}
```

That was easy.

But if you want an *updatable* version of this, for your *desktop-Mac*, then it gets harder.

You could extract the relevant data from Wikidata (or import the whole Multi-GB corpus) and then manage your own local version of the dataset.

Or Install the Blazegraph Triple-Store-DB locally (Docker containers of desktop versions are probably available), then look for a suitable front-end, or build your own front end.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/) would fit the job, except for the log in part.

It is a browser based mini database system with data being categorized with an advanced tagging system.

It can be scripted and customized with little effort as a relatively presentable look out of the box.

Since it is essentially a webpage it can be customized and skinned using the builtin theme and palette system, and further enhanced with the use of conventional CSS styling.

It can be edited locally but when served through the web/network it is mostly read only, unless configured otherwise.

You never specify what the user would be able to accomplish by "logging in", not sure if there is supposed to be any sort of persistence or bookmarks. It can probably be accomplished with heavy customization, but it will not be trivial.